# How can I run multiple applications on one server with the same port?

Tags: vpn, dns, nginx, configuration-managment

I have a vServer and I want to host a VPN server at port 443 and I also want to host a http server with SSL/TLS on port 443. The Server has different domains pointing at him. So I want example.com:443 to serve http content and I want to access the VPN server with vpn.example.com:443

Is this possible, how does it work and how can I configure it?

Comment: It is impossible. When some external packet comes to the port, then network subsystem must know what service this packet must be sent to. To understand this it must parse the packet body and define (by some rule/signature) what type of packet it contains. But IP stack do not analyzes the packet body (so deep). You need, for example, some L7-filter to route this packet to proper service (via localhost subnet with different adresses and/or port numbers). Different domains cannot help - this info is packet body part which can be analyzed by substring/signature.

Answer (score 0):

Domain names aren't relevant here. The networking stack only looks at the IP address and the port number. These two determine, which process receives the incoming packet.

To have two different processes on the same port only works, if they listen on different IP addresses. So, if example.com translates to 10.0.1.1 and vpn.example.com translates to 10.0.1.2, one process could listen on 10.0.1.1:443 and the other process could listen on 10.0.1.2:443.

Having two processes listen on the same address/port combination, e.g. 10.0.1.1:443, doesn't work.

The same applies for IPv6, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Move vCenter to some another port also VPN port has to be on some another port.
Manage nginx to sit on 443 port and make a reverse proxy as a loop back to both services on different ports .
Are you sure the VPN service you've mentioned that are on 443 runs over http protocol or is it some another? If so I would consider reverse proxy with stream option as potential solution. But maybe put VPN to separated port can be nice solution.